# Trying to use a while or do while loop to run a basic math game with certain conditions

Tags: java, eclipse, while-loop, coding-style, do-while

The body of the code is supposed to run until the user has **entered at least 10 questions**, has **not entered more than 20 questions**, and until the student's **percent correct is 85% or higher.**

This is not the whole body but i think im having the most trouble with only the while loop. I have tried multiple combinations to get the code to run as stated above including the way i have given. I have tested all variables and they do keep track as the program runs but how can i get this code to run like the specifications say?

So far i have this:

```
//Declaring int variables to store values of correct/wrong problems
    int numCorrect = 0;
    int numWrong = 0;
    int totalQuestions = 0;
    double percent = 0;
    int subNumCorrect = 0;
    int subNumWrong = 0;
    int addNumCorrect = 0;
    int addNumWrong = 0;
    //Storing the users answers as integers, after asking them for a          solution to a random problem
    //Then looping this code 20 times   
    while((totalQuestions <= 5 && percent >= 85.0 || totalQuestions < 10)) {
        Question theQuestion = new Question();
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("What is the result?" + "\n" + theQuestion.toString());
        int result = scanner.nextInt();

        // Checks if the question is addition/subtraction and correct/wrong, then increases the variables 1 

        if((theQuestion.getOperator() == '+') && (result == theQuestion.determineAnswer()))
            addNumCorrect += 1;
        else if(theQuestion.getOperator() == '+' && (result != theQuestion.determineAnswer()))
            addNumWrong += 1;

        if((theQuestion.getOperator() == '-') && (result == theQuestion.determineAnswer()))
            subNumCorrect += 1;
        else if((theQuestion.getOperator() == '-') && (result != theQuestion.determineAnswer()))
            subNumWrong += 1;

        //Determines if the users answer is correct or not, and displays a message accordingly
        //As well as keeping count of how many correct/wrong answers are attempted by the user and storing them
        //in the variable numCorrect/numWrong
        if(result == theQuestion.determineAnswer()) {
            numCorrect += 1; 
            System.out.println("Congratulations, you got it correct!");
        }
        else if(result != theQuestion.determineAnswer()) {
            numWrong += 1;
            System.out.println("The correct answer for " + theQuestion.toString()
                + " is " + theQuestion.determineAnswer());

        }
        //Increasing value of totalQuestions by one every loop
        totalQuestions++;

        //Multiplying the number of correct problems by 100 and dividing the product by the number of
        //total questions. Then rounding the quotient to get the percentage of correct answers
        percent = Math.round((double)(numCorrect * 100) / (totalQuestions));
    }
    //Progress report displaying how many addition and subtraction problems the user got correct and wrong
    //Then determines the percentage of correct problems the user entered


    System.out.println("\nProgress Report:" + "\nAddition:\nYou got " + addNumCorrect
        + " correct and " + addNumWrong + " incorrect.");
    System.out.println("Subtraction:\nYou got " + subNumCorrect
        + " correct and " + subNumWrong + " incorrect.");
    System.out.println("Number of problems: " + totalQuestions);
    System.out.println("The percent correct: " + percent + "%");

}
```

}

Comment: So what is the problem exactly, is the loop stopping?

Comment: In this case im using 10 and 5 instead of 20 and 10, because it makes it easier and quicker when i test it. So when i run it, it continues to run when it should stop (if the percent correct is higher than 85% AND the user entered at least 5 questions, it should stop). I am very confused as to what condition to use in the while loop to get the conditions stated in the beginning of the question.

Comment: @JawadLeWywadi Where am i missing () ?

Comment: My bad what happens if he reachs 20 quetions but the result is under 85? What do you need it to do i mean.

Comment: The problem comes from your 85% it is not clear what should happen if you have more than 20 questions and you dont have 85%...

Comment: @JawadLeWywadi then the game will stop no matter what if it reaches 20 questions. It must ask atleast 10 questions, and it should stop anywhere between 10-20 questions as long as i have 85% correct.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
while((totalQuestions < 10) || (totalQuestions >= 10 && totalQuestions <= 20 && percent < 85.0)) {
```

Comment: Still not working. When i run this, and answer 10 questions correct AND have 85% or greater correct answers the game should stop, but it doesnt even though i answered all of them correct it continues. It should stop anywhere from 10-20 questions as long as i have 85 or more percent correct. The game should end at 20 questions no matter what. Thank you for the help btw

Comment: No worries! Can you post the code where you calculate the percentage and add to totalQuestions?

Comment: I just posted the rest of it

Comment: Can you please put System.out.println's printing the totalQuestions, number answered correctly, number answered wrong, and percentage within the while loop.  Run the program, and paste your output here.

Answer (score 0):

On top of Kabir's answer I'd just change the structure to:

```
    int numCorrect = 0;
    int numWrong = 0;
    int totalQuestions = 0;
    double percent = 0;
    int subNumCorrect = 0;
    int subNumWrong = 0;
    int addNumCorrect = 0;
    int addNumWrong = 0;
    do{        Question theQuestion = new Question();
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("What is the result?" + "\n" + theQuestion.toString());
        int result = scanner.nextInt();

        // Checks if the question is addition/subtraction and correct/wrong, then increases the variables 1 };
    ...
    while(totalQuestions >= 10 && totalQuestions <= 20 && percent >= 85.0);
```

Then if you want add two if statements to tell you whether it was the 85% that broke the loop or if it was the totalQuestions hitting over 20.

Sorry if the answer is ugly first timer right here =).

Comment: thanks for the response but i tried this condition and it skips the whole body. also a newbie here. good luck

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution.  It will always ask at least 10 questions, yet never more than 20.  In between those, control exits the loop if the percent becomes greater than 85.

It uses a do-while loop to create an object of type Question (which you have done already).  Then immediately increments the number of questions.  Note that the body of a do-while loop will always execute *at least once*.

Next it prompts the user for their answer and stores it (just as your code had done, although declarations were placed outside of the loop).

After your provided code for evaluating the user's response, it computes the percentage of correct questions and stores the value.  Note that the expression needs to be multiplied by 1.0 to avoid integer division (which truncates the result).  That computed value is then used along with the total number of questions in a logical 'OR' to see if the do-while loop should continue.

At the end of the loop body it checks to see if the number of total questions equals or exceeds 20, which is the maximum number of questions permitted per your description.  If the number of questions is greater than or equal to 20, the program exits the loop with a break statement.  I understand this requirement to be correct based on your description.

Outside of the do-while loop it reports the total number of questions and percentage of correct answers for brevity.  Comments were added for clarity.  I hope this helps.  Good luck.

```
    //Declaring int variables to store values of correct/wrong problems
    int numCorrect = 0;
    int numWrong = 0;
    int totalQuestions = 0;
    double percent = 0.0;
    int subNumCorrect = 0;
    int subNumWrong = 0;
    int addNumCorrect = 0;
    int addNumWrong = 0;

    /* Declare a scanner once here, we'll re-use it in the loop */
    Scanner scan = new Scanner( System.in );

    /* Declare a variable to hold the user's input, we'll re-use it too */
    int result = 0;

    //Storing the users answers as integers, after asking them for a solution to a random problem
    //Then looping this code 20 times   
    do{    
        /* Create a new question object */
        Question theQuestion = new Question();

        /* Increment the total number of questions */
        totalQuestions++;

        /* Prompt the user for the question, and obtain the response */
        System.out.print("What is the result? " + theQuestion.toString() + " " );
        result = scan.nextInt();

        // Checks if the question is addition/subtraction and correct/wrong, then increases the variables
        if((theQuestion.getOperator() == '+') && (result == theQuestion.determineAnswer()))
            addNumCorrect += 1;
        else if(theQuestion.getOperator() == '+' && (result != theQuestion.determineAnswer()))
            addNumWrong += 1;

        if((theQuestion.getOperator() == '-') && (result == theQuestion.determineAnswer()))
            subNumCorrect += 1;

        else if((theQuestion.getOperator() == '-') && (result != theQuestion.determineAnswer()))
            subNumWrong += 1;    

        /* Calculate the percentage of correct answers */
        percent = ( (addNumCorrect + subNumCorrect) * 1.0 / totalQuestions );
        System.out.println( "Percent is: " + percent );

        /* Exit the loop if the total number of questions equals or exceeds 20 */
        if( totalQuestions >= 20 )
            break;            

    } while( totalQuestions < 10 || percent < 0.85 );

    /* Report the total number of questions asked and the correct percentage */
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println( "Total number of questions: " + totalQuestions );
    System.out.println( "Percent correct answers: " + percent );
```

Answer (score -1):

As you stated:

The body of the code is supposed to run until the user has entered at least 10 questions, has not entered more than 20 questions, and until the student's percent correct is 85% or higher.

Based on that, your while loop should look like:

```
while(totalQuestions >= 10 && totalQuestions <= 20 && percent >= 85.0) {
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I just tried this but the output completely skips the body using the condition you provided.